# default boot device is missing or boot failed

Tags: boot

i am having a problem of boot failure
i reboot my computer ,after the logo 
there appeared a statement saying checking media ....
after loading there is appearing a blue notification saying 
[default boot device missing or boot failed
insert recovery media and hit any key
then select 'boot manager' to choose a new boot device or to boot recovery media]
and after hitting ok
it brings me to the boot manager with only one option saying [EFI PXE Network]
and after hitting enter
it brings me back to checking media... 
and the same process repeats 
help cause i don't have any idea of whats going on